# Redirect to a result of /bin/ls

Tags: unix, ls

When I use `ls .` (/bin/ls) it returns a list of files.

when "." has directories and I try to redirect `ls .` by `ls . > tmp.txt`,

it contains many symbols like below

```
[1m[36m010202E[39;49m[0m
[1m[36m031403C[39;49m[0m
```

Directory names are 010202E and 031403C

this txt file can be read by "less" but not by vi or any other editors like text wrangler .

How can I avoid this problem?
I know there is a way to delete those characters after making "tmp.txt".

Comment: You (or someone) has done something naughty! `ls` is clever and will never print out colours to a pipe unless you've forced it to do so (`isatty` returns false).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It is likely that there's an alias that makes ls print the output with color. Try to use "ls --color=none", instead.

Comment: Or variable LS_COLORS is set. Check results from `echo $LS_COLORS`